# Firestore timestamp and request.time based security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to fetch list of entities based on *request.time*. Fetch of single entity succeeds while list fails. Can you tell me how to write *where* clause for web sdk query when security rule is so complex?

**Works**:

```
/timer/2339mdynya9Ii358l7DS/smallTimers/15TUTTv6o5dbOZyVEPup
```

**FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.**:

```
/timer/2339mdynya9Ii358l7DS/smallTimers
```

**Working fetcher code (tested without rules)**:

```
firestore.get(`/timer/2339mdynya9Ii358l7DS/smallTimers/15TUTTv6o5dbOZyVEPup`);
firestore.get(`/timer/2339mdynya9Ii358l7DS/smallTimers`);
```

**My structure**:

```
/timer/2339mdynya9Ii358l7DS 
{
  createdAt: "May 12, 2018 at 5:44:51 PM UTC+2"
}
/timer/2339mdynya9Ii358l7DS/smallTimers/15TUTTv6o5dbOZyVEPup
{
  startAfter: 180000
}
```

**My firestore rules**:

```
match /timers/{timerId} {
  match /smallTimers/{smallTimerId} {
    allow read, list: getTimer(timerId).createdAt.toMillis() + resource.data.startAfter < request.time.toMillis();
  }
}
function getTimer(timerId) {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/times/$(timerId)).data
}
```

P.S. Millisecond time is matched and tested correctly (fetch of single entity proves that)

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?

Comment: yup - https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/9YEFfQ0572U/9sGaFG3gBAAJ